# MySQL SELECT returns duplicate and missing rows when using index

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have two InnoDB tables (recipe and recipe_ingredient) in a MySQL 8.1 server that are related based on a single connecting `recipeid` column. I have an API that creates a `WHERE IN ( ... )` set of `recipeid` values to get ingredients for a collection of one or more recipes. Recently I found an example of a SELECT statement that returned very strange results. The total number of rows returned is correct, but there are some expected `recipe_ingredient` rows missing and instead there are duplicated rows that share an `id`. There is a foreign key constraint connecting the tables and if I remove that index the output (while slow) does return all of the correct results without any duplicates. It's not consistent across all combinations of `recipeid` values. If I remove a few of the `recipeid` values from the problematic example, it goes back to returning correct results. Also, if I add a `ORDER BY` clause to the statement it also becomes correct. Perhaps there's a level of caching that I'm not aware of?

While I've found ways to come to the expected outcome in the case of this particular example, I expect that there are other places that use the same SELECT syntax and could be susceptible to the same erroneous output if I can't get to the root cause.

**Example SQL SELECT statement:**

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    recipe_ingredient
WHERE
    recipeid IN (1216133,1218875,1218878,1218879,1218890,1218935,1219273,1219277,1220546,1220645,1220877,1221254,1223242,1223306,1223809,1224594,1227886,1228328,1229189,1231120,1235294,1235865,1236344,1236356,1238042,1238046,1238963,1240679,1243188,1243190,1243191,1243192,1243193,1250575,1258200,1262714,1264472,1264848,1264849,1273733,1277745,1326500,1327436,1331077,1331719,1335118,1340536,1341970,1342143,1346360,1352051,1353907,1353911,1356538,1356653,1358346,1362642,1364615,1364895,1364898,1366402,1370190,1413738,1420984,1420990);
```

**Output of the `EXPLAIN` for the above statement:**

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'recipe_ingredient', NULL, 'range', 'IDX_recipeid', 'IDX_recipeid', '8', NULL, '263', '100.00', 'Using index condition; Using MRR'
```

**Example problem in output results:**

```sql
# id, recipeid, ingredientid, inventoryid, position, name, amount, unit, category, country, updated_at, created_at, percent, brand_id, brand, cost, cost_unit

-- THERE ARE SIX (6) ROWS RETURNED FOR RECIPEID 1258200, BUT THERE ARE SEVEN (7) IN THE TABLE
...
'274056743', '1250575', '3', NULL, '0', 'Whole Wheat Flour', '16', 'oz', 'Adjunct', 'US', '2022-11-24 02:08:21', '2022-11-24 02:08:21', '11.4286', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'lb'
'276454380', '1258200', NULL, '269560', '0', 'self rising bread flour', '3', 'oz', 'Grain', 'US', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2.72727', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Ounces'
'276454381', '1258200', NULL, '269558', '0', 'yeast nutrient', '3', 'lb', 'Grain', 'US', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '43.6364', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Pounds'
'276454382', '1258200', NULL, '297882', '0', 'honey', '3', 'oz', 'Grain', 'US', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2.72727', '42', 'local honey', NULL, 'Ounces'
'276454383', '1258200', NULL, '297883', '0', 'allspice', '2', 'lb', 'Grain', 'US', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '29.0909', '33', 'spice', NULL, 'Pounds'
'276454384', '1258200', '3', NULL, '0', 'Whole Wheat Flour', '1.5', 'lb', 'Adjunct', 'US', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '21.8182', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'lb'
'276454385', '1258200', NULL, '269560', '0', 'self rising bread flour', '3', 'oz', 'Grain', 'US', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2023-02-05 16:39:24', '2.72727', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Ounces'
'265981002', '1262714', NULL, NULL, '0', 'cinnamon ground', '7.5', 'lb', 'Grain', 'US', '2022-03-27 12:39:58', '2022-03-27 12:39:58', '86.3309', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Pounds'
...

-- THERE ARE THREE (3) DUPLICATE ROWS WITH ID 274056694 RETURNED
...
'274056691', '1221254', NULL, '270536', '0', 'rosemary', '4', 'lb', 'Grain', 'US', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '47.7612', '33', 'spice', NULL, 'Pounds'
'274056694', '1221254', NULL, '269560', '0', 'self rising bread flour', '2', 'oz', 'Grain', 'US', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '1.49254', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Pounds'
'274056694', '1221254', NULL, '269560', '0', 'self rising bread flour', '2', 'oz', 'Grain', 'US', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '1.49254', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Pounds'
'274056694', '1221254', NULL, '269560', '0', 'self rising bread flour', '2', 'oz', 'Grain', 'US', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '1.49254', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Pounds'
'274056695', '1223242', NULL, '270536', '0', 'rosemary', '3.75', 'lb', 'Grain', 'US', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '2022-11-24 02:08:20', '37.2671', '33', 'spice', NULL, 'Pounds'
...
```

As stated above, I've tried removing all foreign keys and any other indexes on the tables. Modifying any of the other indexes has no effect on the erroneous example's output, but removing the `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeid` index causes the output to be correct. Having the foreign key constraint on that index also doesn't appear to affect the output.

I have also performed a `OPTIMIZE TABLE recipe, recipe_ingredient` to ensure that the indexes hadn't been somehow corrupted. The command runs and exits with success, but the erroneous output remains.

**Here's a SHOW TABLE output for the two tables in question (with the single seemingly problematic index in place):**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipetoken` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `author_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `folder_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `method` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `styleid` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `style_free` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `batchsize` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `batch_size_mode` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'f',
  `efficiency` float DEFAULT '0',
  `displayunits` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `notes` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci,
  `awardwinning` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `equipment_profile_id` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `url` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `public` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `searchable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `just_imported` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `copy_parent_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `snapshot` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `viewcount` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `average_rating` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_rating` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_ratings` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `share_following` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `imported_from` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `equipment_profile` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci,
  `group_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_edited_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost_currency` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1423534 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `recipe_ingredient` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipeid` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ingredientid` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `inventoryid` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unit` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'lb',
  `category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `percent` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost_unit` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_recipeid` (`recipeid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=283757631 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Try repairing the tables

Comment: @Barmar Using InnoDB engine for these tables, there is no `REPAIR TABLE` operation available. I have used the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` operation on both tables to potentially recreate any erroneous indexing, but the problem persists.

Comment: Then sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Sounds a bit like this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=112802

Comment: Could the problem be caused by using utf8mb3 rather than utf8mb4 (the 8.0.n and 8.1.n defaults)?  CHARSET and COLLATE are involved when your CREATE table information is analyzed.  If this corrects the problem, I can move this to an Answer to be accepted.

Comment: What version are you running?  Does this "fix" the problem?  `ALTER TABLE recipe_ingredient FORCE;`?